# Is it physically possible to mount a manual EF-M or RF lens onto a Canon EF mount DSLR without an adapter?

Tags: lens, canon

I don't care about the electronic communication between the lens and camera. I have a Canon Rebel T7i, and planning to to buy [7artisans 35mm f/0.95](https://7artisans.store/products/35mm-0-95) but this is only available in EF-M mount or RF mount. So I was wondering if I am working with a manual lens like 7artisans 35mm f/0.95 that shouldn't create any problem in focusing and image.